# Karma angular 2 error cannot read foreach of undefined at _normalizeProvider

Tags: testing, angular, karma-runner

I have some issue when I trying to test angular 2 with karma runner and got this error:
http://prntscr.com/awsmor

I don't know what it this (got some errors when I update karma/node/grunt-karma). First got error with undefined character in headers (karma socket)  after that  about  undefined forEach at _normalize.

I don't have any idea how I can fix it and where to looking. Maybe someone can help me?

My Karma.conf
// Karma configuration

```
module.exports = function(config) {


  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-coverage',
    ],
    colors: true,

    autoWatch: true,
    // don't shut down phantom instance for 1 minute
    // because should be able to reuse the instance
    // in one testrun. E.g. run unit tests against
    // sources and minified artifacts
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,

    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    logLevel: config.LOG_ERROR,

    preprocessors: {
      'built/production/**/!(*spec).js': ['coverage']
    },

    files: [{
      pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      included: true,
      watched: true
    }, {
      pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      included: true,
      watched: true
    }, {
      pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
      included: true,
      watched: true
    }, {
      pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
      included: true,
      watched: true
    },
    {
     pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js',
     included: true,
     watched: true
   },
    {
      pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js',
      included: true,
      watched: true
    }, {
      pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js',
      included: true,
      watched: true
    }, {
      pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js',
      included: true,
      watched: true
    }, {
      pattern: 'src/**/*.ts',
      included: false,
      watched: false
    }, {
      pattern: 'built/production/**/*.js',
      included: false,
      watched: true
    }, {
      pattern: 'built/production/**/*.js.map',
      included: false,
      watched: false
    }],

    proxies: {
      // required for component assests fetched by Angular's compiler
      '/src/': './src/'
    },
    port: 9876,
    // singleRun: true,

    reporters: ['progress', 'dots', 'coverage'],
    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [{
        type: 'html'
      }]
    },


  });
};
```

Karma test.shim

```
// Tun on full stack traces in errors to help debugging
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;


jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

// // Cancel Karma's synchronous start,
// // we will call `__karma__.start()` later, once all the specs are loaded.
__karma__.loaded = function() {};


System.config({
  packages: {
    'built': {
      defaultExtension: false,
      format: 'register',
      map: Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).
            filter(onlyAppFiles).
            reduce(function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
              // creates local module name mapping to global path with karma's fingerprint in path, e.g.:
              // './hero.service': '/base/src/app/hero.service.js?f4523daf879cfb7310ef6242682ccf10b2041b3e'
              var moduleName = appPath.replace(/^\/built\//, './').replace(/\.js$/, '');
              pathsMapping[moduleName] = appPath + '?' + window.__karma__.files[appPath]
              return pathsMapping;
            }, {})

      }
    }
});

System.import('angular2/testing').then(function(testing) {
    return System.import('angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter').then(function(providers) {
        testing.setBaseTestProviders(providers.TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
            providers.TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
    });
}).then(function() {
  return Promise.all(
    Object.keys(window.__karma__.files) // All files served by Karma.
    .filter(onlySpecFiles)
    // .map(filePath2moduleName)        // Normalize paths to module names.
    .map(function(moduleName) {
      // loads all spec files via their global module names (e.g. 'base/src/app/hero.service.spec')
      return System.import(moduleName);
    }));
})
.then(function() {
  __karma__.start();
}, function(error) {
  __karma__.error(error.stack || error);
});


function filePath2moduleName(filePath) {
  return filePath.
           replace(/^\//, '').              // remove / prefix
           replace(/\.\w+$/, '');           // remove suffix
}


function onlyAppFiles(filePath) {
  return /^\/built\/.*\.js$/.test(filePath)
}


function onlySpecFiles(path) {
  return /.spec\.js$/.test(path);
}
```

Comment: What is the content of the test that triggers this error? Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar error updating to angular-rc.1, where I had var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser/testing');

testing.setBaseTestProviders(browser.TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, browser.TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);

rc1 deprecated TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS I believe so commenting it out helped a little...

Answer (score 0):

```
testing.setBaseTestProviders(
browser.TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_P‌​ROVIDERS, browser.TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
```

> rc1 deprecated TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS I believe so commenting
>   it out helped